# Regularized Least Squares Objective - Sufficient and Necessary Conditions for Unique Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

Consider some form of Tikhonov regularization, where we seek to minimize the objective described by:

$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} ||Ax - b||^2_2 + \lambda||Dx||^2_2$

(with matrices $A, D$ and vectors $b, x$ of appropriate shape, and some scalar $\lambda >0$). I've read from a text that a unique solution exists for the above objective if and only if $ker(A) \cap ker(D) = \{0\}$, and I'm struggling with the "if" direction of the proof. In particular, I've derived the normal form of the solution, which much satisfy:

$(A^TA + \lambda D^TD)x = A^Tb$

and I've shown that if $z \in ker(A) \cup ker(D)$ for non-zero $z$, then if $x^*$ is a solution to the above normal form, then so is $x^* + z$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with assuming that if $ker(A) \cap ker(D) = \{0\}$, then we must have a unique $x^*$ as the solution.

EDIT: In fact, is there a cleaner solution that does not require proving both conditionals in the biconditional separately like I've formulated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hessian of the convex quadratic objective is $H=A^TA + \lambda D^TD$, and so the solution
is unique **iff** $\ker H$ is trivial.

It is straightforward to check that $Hx = 0$ **iff** $Ax=0 $ and $Dx=0$ and so
$\ker H = \ker A \cap \ker D$.

Note that this is more obvious if we write $H = \begin{bmatrix} A^T & \sqrt{\lambda}D^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ \sqrt{\lambda}D \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: To add a bit of detail, $(A^TA + \lambda D^T D) x = 0 \implies x^T A^TAx + \lambda x^T D^T Dx = 0 \implies \|Ax\|^2 + \lambda \|Dx\|^2 = 0 \implies Ax=0$ and $Dx=0$.

Comment: @littleO: Thanks! I have been doing this for too long, the first time I used the above result (if one can grace it as such) was a paper on minimising pseudoconvex functions almost two decades ago!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Note that
$$
\|Ax-b\|^2 + \lambda \|Dx\|^2
=
\| \begin{bmatrix} A \\ \sqrt{\lambda} D \end{bmatrix} x - \begin{bmatrix} b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\|^2.
$$